# How to create branch of following structure

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

I am trying to create a feature branch in git. I want to create the branches below in the same structure.

```
origin/feature/octRelease  
origin/feature/statistics
```

How can I get the above structure? I want to create the branched above from the master branch.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the branch, just include the folder structure you wish to have as part of the branch. The `origin` part can be ignored, as you will create your branch locally at first.
You can also consider using [gitflow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow) to make managing your branches easier.